# The flask api route request get params missing error

Tags: python, flask, postman

In my flask project, I have a route:

```
@app.route('/api/d/u', methods=['POST'])
def update(name, domain_list, pem_key, pem_cert, origin_ips):  # name, domain_list, pem_key, pem_cert, origin_ips
    return "update"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

but in my postman I want to test the api,

[image: You see the params]

when I send request but get TypeError:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TypeError: update() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'name', 'domain_list', 'pem_key', 'pem_cert', and 'origin_ips' // Werkzeug Debugger</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="?__debugger__=yes&amp;cmd=resource&amp;f=style.css"
        type="text/css">
        <!-- We need to make sure this has a favicon so that the debugger does
         not by accident trigger a request to /favicon.ico which might
         change the application state. -->
     ......
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
TypeError: update() missing 5 required positional arguments: 'name', 'domain_list', 'pem_key', 'pem_cert', and 'origin_ips'

-->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters for your route function are only filled with a GET Request. Example:

```
@app.route('/api/d/u/<name>', methods=['GET'])
def update(name):
    return "update"

#Example Call would be GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/d/u/myname
```

For your POST Example you may need to import `request` from flask and since you are retrieving form-data, you can extract it like this:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/d/u', methods=['POST'])
def update():
    formdata = request.form
    # Extract form-data: name = formdata['name']
    return "update"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: What's the usage of  params in`update(name, domain_list, pem_key, pem_cert, origin_ips)`?

Comment: These params are only filled when the sender mentions them in the route/path/url as shown above: '/api/d/u/<name>/<domain_list>/...'. But since you are sending a POST and you are transmitting the information in the Body, you need to use request.fom

Comment: so, only `GET` method can use them, right?

Comment: `POST` requests would also fill these params if they are mentioned in the URL. - or obviously if you call your update function somewhere else in code. e.g. `update('myname', ['domain1', 'domain2'],...)`

Answer (score -1):

Because you defined your function with arguments, flask expects to get them from the route. If you want to use your current implementation, you should do something like

```
from flask import app, request

@app.route('/api/d/u', methods=['POST'])
def update():  # name, domain_list, pem_key, pem_cert, origin_ips
    # data = request.get_json() # use if you send data as json
    data = request.form # use if you send data as a form
    name = data["name"]
    domain_list = data["domain_list"]
    # ... continue with other fields
    return "update"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: I edited the answer to take into account the fact that data was sent in a form and not a json